# Does LIST_HEAD macro re-initialize all variables?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am writing some Kernel code using the LINUX built in linked list. I am wondering if multiple calls to INIT_LIST_HEAD will re-initialize all of the variables that I have created. What is the behavior of the INIT_LIST_HEAD macro?

Here is some example code:

```
INIT_LIST_HEAD(same_list);
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     INIT_LIST_HEAD(same_list);
     add_to_tail_of_same_list
```

Will the two lists point to the same list, namely will the same_list in the final iteration have 10 elements? I'm asking the question, cause I want to use INIT_LIST_HEAD inside the for loop instead of initializing outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INIT_LIST_HEAD` [does the following](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h#L25):

```
static inline void INIT_LIST_HEAD(struct list_head *list)
{
        list->next = list;
        list->prev = list;
}
```

So if you call it from inside the loop, you'll effectively be reinitializing it 10 times, and the first 9 elements you added will be lost.